# start() method called for a thread from a start() ... confusing

Tags: java, multithreading, lwjgl

I've been fiddling with creating a thread on which the rendering runs, and I've come across this way of implementing it:

```
Class Main implements Runnable {
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;

public void start() {
            running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "renderingThread")
    thread.start(); //calls run()
}

    public void run() {

    init(); //init glfw + create window

    while(running) {
        update();
        render();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start()
    }
```

Note that only the sections of the code that are related to threads have been included.

Now, the **program flow** looks something like this (correct me if I'm wrong): Construct new object of type/class Main (hence, reserve a place on the heap). Then, the *start*() method of object of type Main is called. *running* boolean is set to true. Then, a new thread is created via constructor *Thread (Runnable target, String name)* - in my case, the first parameter is *this* keyword, meaning that the reference of the object of type Main is passed as the first parameter (since the method has been called by the object of type Main). Then, the next line is what fiddles me the most. The *thread* reference calls the method *start*(), but it somehow refers to the *run*() method. How?

I'd be very thankful for a thorough explanation of how *start*() method for a thread object can refer to the *run*() method.

Comment: This is code you - presumably - wrote. The existence of the `start()` method is entirely your choice, and has nothing to do with the fact that a thread itself is started using a method that is also called `start()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new `Thread` with a `Runnable` target of `this` (the instance of `Main` class). `Main implements Runnable` means the method `run()` is overridden.   The `Thread` class itself implements `Runnable`.

When you start the thread with the configuration above, the method `start()` causes the thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine then calls the `Thread` object's `run()` method. It's said in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--). If you are curious, see the source code of the [java.lang.Thread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.start%28%29).

You can achieve the same effect with a simpler approach:

```
public class Main implements Runnable { 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("New thread");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Main()).start();
        System.out.println("Main thread");
    }
}
```

Comment: To say that `start()` indirectly calls `run()` could be misleading. Somebody could get the idea that `start()` calls something that calls something that ... calls `run()`. But that's not what happens. The call to `run()` happens in a different thread from the `start()` call.

Comment: @jameslarge Nope. See the source code linked in my answer. When you invoke the start() method which calls private native void start0(), a new thread is created and then the run() method is executed in this new one - it’s indirect.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis, Usually, when somebody says "A indirectly calls B," they are talking about something that happens in a single thread.  If you say that `start()` indirectly calls `run()`, then a person who understands threading knows what you mean, but a noob does not.  A noob has no way of knowing that you are using the phrase "indirect call" in an unusual way.  There's a lot of noobs out there writing multi-threaded code without any substantial understanding of what threads are, and that's who these answers should target.

Comment: @jameslarge I consider myself as a noob in multithreading. Moreover, it's not fair to refer to anyone as noob since everyone has been one. It's right that I might understand my answer differently than OP since out Java knowledge vary and mainly I am not a native English speaker so I have not such right... taste of words (if I can say it like that). Thus, thank you for the feedback, I edit my answer. :))

Comment: I am a noob in many things.  I didn't know it was an offensive word.  I should have guessed.  If there are any words left that still are inoffensive, they probably won't last long.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--)

When start() is called on the `Thread` Object it creates a new Thread and calls the `run()` method on that thread.